# MS SQL : Check multiple conditions and return combined result as field in select statement

Tags: sql-server

I am implementing MS SQL query in which I need to check all conditions and get a merged result in one field(OupputField) as a string.

**Table: Customer**

```
Id  Customer Type Active
------------------------
1   John     1    1     
2   Bob      2    0     
3   TOM      0    1
```

I trying to get **OupputField** values by checking **ALL** different cases. but it checks for one true condition and returns the result. I need to check all the cases and need to return combine result as OutputField

**Expected Output:**

```
Id  Customer Type Active OutputField
--------------------------------------
1   John     1    1      Type1, Active
2   Bob      2    0      Type2
3   TOM      0    1      Active
```

**MS SQL Query:**

```
select 
    Id,
    Customer,
    TypeId
    Active
    COALESCE
    (
     CASE 
        WHEN  TypeId = 1 
        THEN  'Type1'
     END,
     CASE 
        WHEN  Active = 1 
        THEN  'Active'
     END
    )
from Customer
```

Am I doing something wrong? Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
select case when type = 0 and active = 0 then ''
            when type = 0 and active = 1 then 'Active'
            when type > 0 and active = 0 then 'Type' + cast(type as varchar)
            when type > 0 and active = 1 then 'Type' + cast(type as varchar) + ', Active'
       end as result
from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp(Id int, Customer varchar(20), TypeId int, Active int)
INSERT INTO #tmp (Id,Customer,TypeId,Active) VALUES(1,'John',1,1)
INSERT INTO #tmp (Id,Customer,TypeId,Active) VALUES(2,'Bob',2,0)
INSERT INTO #tmp (Id,Customer,TypeId,Active) VALUES(3,'TOM',0,1)
INSERT INTO #tmp (Id,Customer,TypeId,Active) VALUES(4,'Jim',0,0)

select Id,    Customer,
    TypeId
    Active,
    CASE WHEN TypeID >0 THEN 'TypeId' + CAST(TypeID as varchar(3)) ELSE '' END +
        CASE WHEN TypeID > 0 AND Active > 0 THEN ', ' ELSE '' END + 
            CASE WHEN Active > 0 THEN 'Active'  ELSE '' END OutputField
from #tmp
```